# Is this a bad practice with static classes and thread safety?

Tags: c#, thread-safety

Assuming I'm not using the lock statement, is this a bad practice?

```
public static class Foo
{
  public static string Bar()
  {
    bool working;

    while (working)
    {
      // Loop until ready to run.
    }

    working = true;

    // Do stuff here.

    working = false;
    return "done."
  }
}
```

Edit -

After trying something like this, I realize it's not feasible for several reasons. I was just curious.. The example I posted doesn't even work.

Comment: Just curious - what was the goal here?  Why were you trying to avoid the lock in the first place?

Comment: I wasn't trying to avoid it -- I was just trying to understand why people don't use loop locking instead of the lock statement :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Loop is a CPU consuming process.

I mean if everything you do is just waiting. It is not a good.

Comment: That's true, too - if you're going to loop like that, you should do something to reduce your cpu usage, like Thread.CurrentThread.Sleep(0) in the loop.

Comment: Even if Thread.Sleep is used, this is still a terrible waste of CPU. Polling is your enemy; waiting should be event-driven (like lock). See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy-wait

Comment: +1 to configurator for the reference.  That's why my answer suggested going to locks or semaphores.

Answer (score 4):

First off, working is private to the method, so it will have no effect.  2 threads calling this will each have their own "working".  You'd need to make it a static field to have an effect.

Even then, you can get race conditions.  2 threads can hit this at the same time, pass through the while(working) condition, and then set working = true; and be doing things at the same time.

Using a lock or a semaphore will help solve this.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean that `working` will be modified from another thread, there are two problems:

1. You should make working into a `volatile static` member. Volatile will tell the compiler not to try anything "clever" in optimization.
2. You've written what is called a "spin lock". There are specialized circumstances where that is the best approach. But usually it's a terrible idea because your thread will consume CPU until the `working` variable is set.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is bad practice.

Why would you not using the lock statement? Look at the [Monitor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor(VS.71).aspx) class, I can provide mutual exclusion and synchronization.

The spinning loop and non-threadsafe variable working shouldn't be used.

Comment: I was just curious -- I have no intentions of using anything like this.. I would use the lock statement.. I should've tried this approach before asking, but I didn't.. :)

Answer (score 1):

There is another issue that if working were visible to multiple threads (as another poster mentioned, it is a local variable), as written right now there is no guarantee that other cores in the system will see the updates to working in the right order.  A memory barrier, such as System.Threading.Thread.MemoryBarrier, is needed to guarantee that the write to working doesn't get re-ordered by the CPU past "Do stuff here."

But you should consider using locks instead.  Lock-free programming is incredibly hard to get right.

Answer (score 0):

Using locking is the only way to prevent concurrency problems (other that not doing it).

```
public static class Foo
{
  private static object barLock = new object();

  public static string Bar()
  {
    lock (barLock)
    {
      // Do work
      return "Done";
    }
  }
}
```